# Import a directory with files and force-overwrite even if the directory already exists

Tags: svn, visualsvn

I need to import a folder (say `Project`) with files into SVN even though the folder already exists on the server with the files.

Note : I have set up my repository as *write-through proxy*, so if I checkout the folder, do the changes and commit back, I get a "working copy out of date" error.

Is there any command-line tool to do this? Or any other ideas?

Comment: Why can't you simply make a checkout, copy the files (overwriting) and then do an `svn add` on all files contained in the folder? New files will be added and files already controlled by svn will be skipped. Note: copy the content of the folder (the files), not the folder itself.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention... I have setup the repository as Write-through proxy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read `svn help import` and use it. If you task **really** is

> Add unversion tree from custom location into existing repository

`svn import /PATH/TO/PROJECT protocol://URL/IN/REPOSITORY`

will add as result `Project` as child to `URL/IN/REPOSITORY`

Just to note: import will appear as commit in repository

Comment: this does not overwrite, like the OP requested. I am having the same problem that svn import does not overwrite files if they already exist in SVN

Answer (score 0):

Since SVN Import doesn't overwrite, I did the following:

1) Deleted the outdated files from the SVN Repository using SVN Manager.

2) Imported the latest files into the repository.

3) Checked Out the files back into the folder with the latest files.